# Show the parent post through child post content

Tags: mysql

I would like to show the parent post through its children post by filtering the content of the child post/parent post.  I have a table `message`. And this is how it looks like:

```
m_id   m_parent_post_id   m_user_id  m_topic  m_message  m_status  m_by_admin

1           0               1234      t1       first..    replied      0
2           1               1234      null     second..   na           0
3           1               1234      null     third..    na           1
4           1               1234      null     fourth..   na           0
5           0               2222      t2       first..    replied      2
6           5               2222      null     second     na           0
7           0               1111      t3       second     new          0
```

Table explanation:

- m_id is auto increment
- m_parent_post_id the m_id of the parent post, 0 means that the row is
  a parent post
- m_topic is null if its a child post
- m_status is the status of the parent post, if its `new`, `replied` by the user or `answered` by admin. na is for child post only.
- m_by_admin is the status of the row if it is 0 meaning the user was the one who added it, 1 for admin reply, and 2 for admin who created the message.

So in here, I am trying to select all the message which `m_message` contains *second*  string or words and it (the rows not the parent id) should be only created by the user. After selecting it, it should show only the parent post of it wherein the `m_status` is `replied`.

```
SELECT * FROM message where m_message LIKE '%second%' WHERE m_by_admin = 0 AND
```

.... Did not know what's next.

This will only show the child post, not the parent. Should show the m_id `1` and `5` as expected output.

```
 1           0               1234      t1       first..    replied      0
 5           0               2222      t2       first..    replied      2

 7           0               1111      t3       second     new          0
```

Need help with this. Any faster query if possible, I have hundreds of rows of parent and child post.

Comment: can you add the expected output or a sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @Sinto I have added expected output from my post.

Comment: So you only need parent posts?

Comment: Yes, only the parent post.

Comment: Do you want to show post 7 as well? it matches '%second%' but is a parent post.

Comment: @Nick Yes, the search should include parent and child posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `P`.* FROM message P WHERE 
`P`.`m_id` IN (SELECT `C`.`m_parent_post_id` FROM message C 
WHERE `C`.`m_message` LIKE '%second%' AND `C`.`m_by_admin` = 0)
OR (`P`.`m_message` LIKE '%second%' AND `P`.`m_by_admin` = 0 AND `P`.`m_parent_post_id` = 0);
```

JOIN user table as:

```
SELECT `P`.*, `U`.`user_id` FROM message P 
JOIN user U ON (`U`.`user_id` = `P`.`m_user_id`) 
WHERE `P`.`m_id` IN 
    (SELECT `C`.`m_parent_post_id` FROM message C 
    WHERE `C`.`m_message` LIKE '%second%' AND `C`.`m_by_admin` = 0) 
    OR (`P`.`m_message` LIKE '%second%' AND `P`.`m_by_admin` = 0 AND `P`.`m_parent_post_id` = 0);
```

Comment: Why do you think this(your latest answer) is better than `SELECT * FROM message WHERE 
    `m_id` IN (SELECT `m_parent_post_id` FROM message 
        WHERE `m_message` LIKE '%second%' AND `m_by_admin` = 0)`?

Comment: I just added alias for the table for better readability. There are 2 section first inner query takes child posts from `like` clause, after using out of that the parent post is taking

Comment: Also the parent post should be included in the searching, example the message was created by user with no replies or child post.

Comment: Do you need search for parent posts also? I think you will get the expected out from above query

Comment: which one is that post

Comment: can you add a expected out for that?

Comment: Can you check now

Comment: Hi @Sinto I am inserting a inner join with `user` table where can I put it? I tried `SELECT `P`.* FROM message P INNER JOIN user U ON(`P`.`m_user_id` = `U`.`user_id`)WHERE 
`P`.`m_id` IN (SELECT `C`.`m_parent_post_id` FROM message C 
WHERE `C`.`m_message` LIKE '%second%' AND `C`.`m_by_admin` = 0)
OR (`P`.`m_message` LIKE '%second%' AND `P`.`m_by_admin` = 0 AND `P`.`m_parent_post_id` = 0);` but doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your help!